# How to Publish Xamarin.Forms Projected WASM App to FTP Correctly.?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, webassembly, uno-platform

I'm developing a WASM app with Xamarin.Forms & UNO Platform. When I use the "Publish" section in WASM project with destination FTP, the WASM created web app looks unfamiliar with debug app. My custom fonts and images disappeared and app cannot run second time. Debug mode is on IIS, my FTP server is Linux hosting js and php enabled.

Is this the problem?

What is the correct method of publishing the WASM app to FTP ? Thanks.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: You want to publish a WASM app using FTP right? Your issue copying the file through the FTP or running the app once copied in the FTP server?

Comment: Copying succeeded. The view of app is so different from debug mode in my development area. My custom fonts and embedded images are gone.

Comment: Once deployed in the FTP how are you accessing the app? Are you deploying Debug or Release?